# How do i use keys function whithin python instance classes

Tags: python, class, dictionary, key

This is not working looks like "keys" function is broken... it lists everything in the class AND referenced classes. what am i doing wrong ... the more i try python the more i am convinced its programmed by incompetents...  same thing in php is a 2 min thing. :-/

```
class Nodes:
  nodes = {}
  def nd_add(self,nId):
    self.nodes[nId]= Node(nId)
  def nd_print(self):  
    for node in self.nodes.keys():
  #    print node
      self.nodes[node].nd_print()
  def keys(self):
    return self.nodes.keys()   


class Node:
  childs = Nodes()  
  ddid = False
  def __init__(self,nid):
    self.ddid = nid
  def nd_print(self):
    print self.ddid
    print self.childs.keys()
   # self.nodes.nd_print()      


root =  Nodes()
root.nd_add("bob")
root.nd_add("dub")
root.nodes["bob"].childs.nd_add("sponge")
print "root"
root.nd_print()
```

this is what comes out:

```
root
sponge
['sponge', 'bob', 'dub']
bob
['sponge', 'bob', 'dub']
dub
['sponge', 'bob', 'dub']
```

py version is 2.7

Comment: You are using class attributes instead of instance attributes for 'nodes' in 'Nodes' and for 'childs' in 'Node'. class attributes are shared by all instances of a class. You should create a constructor (`__init__`) and initialize 'nodes', 'childs' and 'ddid' in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing instance variables with class variables.

Including a variable definition within the class definition, as you did above, introduces a class variables, this means, the variable does not belong to individual objects, but exists only once for the class.

Consider this example:

```py
class MyClass:
    a = [5]                                                                                               

    def __init__(self):                                                                                   
        self.b = [10]                                                                                     

ins1 = MyClass()                                                                                          
ins2 = MyClass()                                                                                          
print("ins1", ins1.a, ins1.b)                                                                             
print("ins2", ins2.a, ins2.b)                                                                             
ins1.a.append(6)                                                                                          
ins1.b.append(11)                                                                                         
print("ins1", ins1.a, ins1.b)                                                                             
print("ins2", ins2.a, ins2.b)
```

Outputs:

```
ins1 [5] [10]                                                                                             
ins2 [5] [10]                                                                                             
ins1 [5, 6] [10, 11]                                                                                      
ins2 [5, 6] [10]
```

Notice how `a` changed for both, and `b` only changed for `ins1`.
You can also do something like `print(MyClass.a)`, because `a` belongs to `MyClass`, but not `print(MyClass.b)`, because the class itself does not have an attribute `b`, only its instances do. This is not because Python was designed by incompetent programmers, it is because *everything is an object in Python*, including the class. (`type(MyClass)` returns `class`) Therefore, the class itself can have attributes, which are different from the attributes of its instances! The instances can access those variables with the `.attribute` syntax, but it is still only a reference to the class variable.

Section 9.3.5 of [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) explains this, and gives the exact same mistake as an example, as well as use cases for class variables.

note: if you are new to python, you should probably stick to python 3, as 2 is not supported anymore. The differences are minor though.

Comment: hum that is just so weird! i guess that's what they mean by pythonic ... the more i look at this the more i figure its just written by  a mad kid somewhere... :-/  no other language does it like this ... and by that i mean pascal, basic, php, c++, java (+script) etc... i guess ill have to bang my head at every turn... i did this in like 15 min in php :-/ no issues.

Answer (score 0):

- From other answers instance variables and class variables should be clear
- I have done some code modifications. You can use it as a reference

  ```
  class Nodes:
      def __init__(self):
          self.nodes = {}    # instance variable
      def nd_add(self,nId):
          self.nodes[nId]= Node(nId)
      def nd_print(self, parent=None):
          for node in self.nodes.keys():
              #    print node
              self.nodes[node].nd_print(parent)
      def keys(self):
          return self.nodes.keys()

  class Node:
      ddid = False
      def __init__(self,nid):
          self.ddid = nid
          self.childs = None      # instance variable
      def nd_print(self, parent=None):
          if parent is None:
              print '%s is a parent Node: '%self.ddid
          else:
              print '%s is a child node of %s'%(self.ddid, parent)
          if self.childs is not None:
              self.childs.nd_print(self.ddid)
      def nd_add_child(self, child_id):
          self.childs = Nodes()
          self.childs.nd_add(child_id)

  root =  Nodes()
  root.nd_add("bob")
  root.nd_add("dub")
  root.nodes["bob"].nd_add_child("sponge")
  root.nodes['bob'].childs.nodes['sponge'].nd_add_child('xxx') # this needs a proper function
  print "root"
  root.nd_print()
  ```